# Google Sheets: Statement to convert emoji's/text into a percentage and add it up at the end

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to make a google sheet that takes in information from a google form and then converts those answers into a Percentage to be added up at the end.

So for example the form has a section where people can either pick a thumbs up or thumbs down emoji for an answer and it will add that emoji to the sheet. Is there a way to say something like

IF((A2 = ) Percent = 15%), ELSE(Percent = 0%) to indicate either a thumbs up or down % score.

I'm not too familiar with google sheet syntax just yet and nothing I've looked for has worked so far, would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF(H2:H="",ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(H2:H,"",1)*15%))))
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs and format the results as percentage)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: Happy I could help.